# Google image search strange redirects

Tags: html, image, google-image-search

I discovered a strange behaviour in google image search. Let me start with an example:

I want to find a picture of a cat. I type cat in google images, press enter and I pick this little one:

> http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/157/1562-cute-little-cat.jpg

[I just inserted the link of the original image]. When you try to follow this link at the very first time, it will do two redirects:

1. Request URL:http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/157/1562-cute-little-cat.jpg
2. Request URL:http://www.freegreatpicture.com/1562
3. Request URL:http://www.freegreatpicture.com/cat/photo-1562

The response to the 3. request content types is text/html. Basically it loads the website where this cute kitty lives. So now the kittens images is cached, if you would try one more time to hit this URL:

> http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/157/1562-cute-little-cat.jpg

It would load the image. Super! But what about when you would try this from a native client app? I mean I would want to download the image and show it in a picture box. It wouldn't load the image and you would have no idea why. It would gave back the text/html content what is not image/jpeg.

My question is, is anyone met with this problem? Any work around that to filter out this kinds of urls?